# How to change a node point from a circle to a cross?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I may be going about this the wrong way, but I'm trying to highlight a specific point on a graph using tikz and pgfplots. Currently I'm using a node to draw a circle round the point - however, I would ideally like to change thus to something more like an 'x'.

My code is as follows, and any help would be immensely appreciated.

```
\documentclass[1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = {Good 1},
    ylabel = {Good 2},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=450,
    ymin=0, 
    ymax=450,
    ytick={0,100,200,300,400,500},
    scaled y ticks = false,
    ]
    \addplot[] file[] {jointppf.dat};
    \node[draw,circle] ( ) at (250,300) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about tickmarks? You may place it at any point. Check the manual for it.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete, compilable small document (MWE), that we can provide a complete solution. Meanwhile test if use of  `\node at (250,300) {$\times$};`  and/or `\addplot [mark=x] coordinates {(250,300)};` gives what you after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use : `\addplot[mark=x,mark size=3] coordinates {(250,300)};`

```
\documentclass[1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = left,
        xlabel = {Good 1},
        ylabel = {Good 2},
        xmin=0,
        xmax=450,
        ymin=0, 
        ymax=450,
        ytick={0,100,200,300,400,500},
        scaled y ticks = false,
        ]
        \addplot[] coordinates
        {(0,420) (250,300) (400,0)};
        \addplot[mark=x,mark size=3] coordinates
        {(250,300)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or: `\node at (axis cs:250,300) {\sffamily{x}};`

```
\documentclass[1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = left,
        xlabel = {Good 1},
        ylabel = {Good 2},
        xmin=0,
        xmax=450,
        ymin=0, 
        ymax=450,
        ytick={0,100,200,300,400,500},
        scaled y ticks = false,
        ]
        \addplot[] coordinates
        {(0,420) (250,300) (400,0)};
        \node at (axis cs:250,300) {\sffamily{x}};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]